# What is the equivalent query of laravel on this?

Tags: laravel

This is the native sql:

```
$sql = "Select count(name) from users Where email = 't@t.com' and user_id = 10";
```

I have this laravel code:

```
$checker = Customer::whereEmailAndUserId("t@t.com",10)->count("name");
```

Is this a correct way to do it in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

The option you are trying is incorrect

here is the right option

```
$users = \App\Customer::where('email','t@t.com')
                  ->where('user_id',10)
                  ->count()
```

Explanation of above code

`App\Customer` is the Model class and I am trying to read records `where email = 't@t.com` you can use various comparison operators like `<`,`>` and so on and you can also use the same function to for string pattern matching also

Eg.

```
$users = \App\Customer::where('email','%t.com')
                  ->where('user_id',10)
                  ->count()
```

You can use the same `where` function for Null Value test also

Eg.

```
$users = \App\Customer::where('email','=', null)
                  ->where('user_id',10)
                  ->count()
```

The above where clause will be converted to `is null` test of the SQL

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `where` helper function and pass an array of checks. For example in your code it will be:

```
$checker = Customer::where([
                ['email', '=', 't@t.com'],
                ['user_id' '=', '10']
            ])->count();
```

Note: Please use the appropriate column name as it in table.

Comment: this is wrong, you didn't specify in the column name inside the count - `count(name)`.  Check my sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Customer` model represents table `users`, you'll get query with eloquent like this:

```
Customer::where('email', 't@t.com')->where('user_id', 10)->select(\DB::raw('count(name)'))->get();
```